# Create a subset of geometries which intersects with each other

Tags: qgis, postgis, postgresql, intersection

I have a set of geometry in my PostgreSQL table that consists of Points, Linestrings & Polygons. From this set I need to create a subset of geometries which intersects with each other.
I need a method without looping through each one of them as there can be more than 1000 geometries at once.

I need to fetch the geometries that are marked in red in this image

[image: I need to fetch the geometries that are marked in red in this image]

Comment: Which data type are we talking about?

Comment: Geometry datatype in postgres table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a spatial index for your table and make a self join with SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table a INNER JOIN my_table b ON a.geom && b.geom
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) and ST_AsText(a.geom) <> ST_AsText(b.geom);
```

&& is the operator for the overlaping of the minimal boundary rectangles (MBR) and it uses spatial index.
For 1000 geometry it should be fast enough, if few overlapings are among the MBR of the geometries (your figure shows that).

Comment: Thanks a lot @Zoltan . This solved my issue. Final Query that i used => SELECT * FROM my_table a INNER JOIN my_table b ON a.geom && b.geom
WHERE ST_Intersects(a.geom, b.geom) and st_astext(a.geom) <> st_astext(b.geom);   Let me know if i can improve this even more.

Comment: I think st_astext comparison may be constly. I would use the primary key of the table in the comparison, the fastest a integer ID primary key would be.

Comment: Using the key sped it up from 12 s to 2 s with 30k polygons

Comment: Strictly speaking `&&` is not necessary since `ST_Intersects` automatically includes an index filter.

Comment: Note that this will add a match (row) with `a.geom` **for each** `b.geom` that it intersects with; in OPs example set above, the middle polygon of those three-in-a-row will be present twice. There are better and faster solutions for this kind of task than needing to use a `DISTINCT` on a large and heavily computed result set with unnecessarily duplicated information - mainly using an `EXISTS` filter, or `ST_ClusterDBSCAN` with `eps:=0`.